# Always return all row, even when query has no result

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a "tt_Results" table which contains exactly three row / ID like:

```
ID | ResultType
---------------
1  |  first
1  |  second
1  |  third
```

My query looks like:

```
select t.resultType
from tt_Results 
where ID = 1;
```

Normally, this query should return all the three row. My problem is if one or more row not exist I must union all the three "type".

```
 select res.* from
(
 select resultType, '1' as exists 
 from tt_Results 
 where ID = 1

 union all  

 select 'first' resulttype, '0' as exists
 from dual
 where not exists (
   select resulttype
   from tt_Results 
   where resulttype = 'first' and ID = 1)

 union all

 select 'second' resulttype, '0' as exists
 from dual
 where not exists (
   select resulttype
   from tt_Results 
   where resulttype = 'second' and ID = 1)

 union all

 select 'third' resulttype, '0' as exists
 from dual
 where not exists (
   select resulttype
   from tt_Results 
   where resulttype = 'third' and ID = 1)
) res
```

The final query result looks good but it is very slow. Anyone have a better PL/SQL solution for it? Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left join to your table from a table of all types, using a `case` to calculate `exists` based on whether a join was made or not:

```
select
    type,
    case when resultType is null then '0' else '1' end as exists
from (select 'first' type from dual union 
      select 'second' from dual union 
      select 'third' from dual) t
left join tt_Results on resultType = type
    and ID = 1
```

Note that the condition `ID = 1` is part of the *join* condition, *not* in a `where` clause.

---

I recommend creating a 3-row table for the types, then the query would become simply:

```
select
    type,
    case when resultType is null then '0' else '1' end as exists
from types
left join tt_Results on resultType = type
    and ID = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a subquery to hold the result types you're interested in, and then using a partitioned outer join, like so:

```
with tt_results as (select 1 id, 'first' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 1 id, 'second' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 1 id, 'third' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 2 id, 'second' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 2 id, 'third' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 3 id, 'first' resulttype from dual),
          dummy as (select 1 position, 'first' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 2 position, 'second' resulttype from dual union all
                    select 3 position, 'third' resulttype from dual)
select res.id,
       d.resulttype,
       case when res.resulttype is not null then 1 else 0 end res_exists
from   dummy d
       left outer join tt_results res partition by (res.id) on d.resulttype = res.resulttype
order by res.id,
         d.position;

        ID RESULTTYPE RES_EXISTS
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 first               1
         1 second              1
         1 third               1
         2 first               0
         2 second              1
         2 third               1
         3 first               1
         3 second              0
         3 third               0
```

Adrian Billington has produced an excellent article on [partititioned outer joins](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312_) if you want to learn more about them.

If your tt_results table could contain more resulttypes than you're interested in, you might want/need to add a predicate to only grab the rows from the dummy subquery, otherwise you could get ids where all 3 resulttypes don't exist (although that may be what you want to see).

---

ETA: This will work if you need to select multiple ids in one go.